# Finitely generated module

Tags: modules

If a finitely generated module $M$ injected in a free module, then would the image of  $M$ be a  free finitely generated module?

Comment: I meet that question while I was testing the coherence in the case of representation theory of quivers.  I think that my question was so interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If a finitely generated $M$ is mapped into the free module on some set $X$, then the image of each generator of $M$ is a linear combination of finitely many elements of $X$. The images of the finitely many generators of $M$ involve, in this way, only finitely many elements of $X$ altogether. So the given map sends $M$ into the submodule freely generated by those finitely many elements of $X$.

Comment: Firstly i would  like  to thank you for the answer.  I meet that question while I was testing the coherence in the case of representation theory of quivers.